# In what cases would fscanf overflow memory?

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a linked list I implemented that works fine for various file inputs (it reads them line by line and inserts them.)

```
void insert_words(FILE* file, node_type* list)
{
    char buffer[12];
    int length = 0;

    while (!feof(file)){
        fscanf(file, "%s", buffer);//buffer contains the string/name
        length = strlen(buffer);
        if (length != 0) { 
            insert_sorted(list, buffer);
        }
    } //while

}
```

Given this code, I'm seeing issues which when fscanf is executed with the given sample input after reading in 'fff', things seem to go sour.

```
one
two

three ee
fff
ee
```

As ee is being parsed:

```
list = 0x009dfac0 {name=0x009dfac0 "one" next=0x00c98c08 {name=0x00c98c08 "three" next=0x00c98ba0 {name=0x00c98ba0 "two" ...} } }
```

After the next token:

```
list = 0x009dfac0 {name=0x009dfac0 "ee" next=0x009df068 {name=0x009df068 "È”ü\xf\x1" next=0x0ff7caa0 {msvcr110d.dll!_except_handler4(_EXCEPTION_RECORD *, _EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION_RECORD *, _CONTEXT *, void *)} {...} }
```

When examining my list, the 'next' pointer is corrupted immediately after fscanf is fired off. What are the potential causes?

Inserted sort upon request:

```
void insert_sorted(node_type* list, char* value)
{
    // Copy our pointer so we can move around
    node_type *n = (node_type*) malloc(sizeof *n); 
    node_type *loc = NULL;
    node_type *tmp;
    node_type dat;
    node_type* prev = list;
    node_type* head = list;

    n->next = NULL;
    strcpy(n->name, value); 

    // First element, assign immediately
    if( strcmp(list->name, "") == 0 )
    {
        *list = *n;
        return;
    }


    while(head != NULL)
    {
        // We should do a comparison to see if one is greater than another
        int cmp_result = strcmp(value, head->name);

        // If the value is bigger, this means the value needs to be inserted after
        if(cmp_result > 0)
        {           
            loc = head;
        }

        else if (cmp_result < 0) // this needs to be ahead
        {

            if(prev == head)    
            {
                dat = *head;
                *head = *n;
                head->next = &dat;
                return;
            }

            prev->next = n;
            n->next = head;
            return;
        }

        else if(cmp_result == 0)
        {
            free(n);
            return; // duplicate, die
        }


        // Advance to the next pointer
        prev = head;
        head = head->next;
    }


    // You've reached the end, that must mean you've succesfully reached the point to insert

    tmp = loc->next; // get the value we're going to end up detaching
    n->next = tmp; // link the two together
    loc->next = n;

}
```

Comment: There is no `next` in the code shown - the `insert_sorted()` may well be where the problem is. Having said that, change `%s` to `%12s` to prevent buffer overrun.

Comment: @Keith That does not seem to do anything -- I'd show my insertion method but it's fairly long. Are there some possibilities I could narrow done? Everything I read said fscanf prevented overflows, so I'm not sure how doing a read could possibly butcher another variable so bad..

Comment: @Keith: it should be `%11s` if the char array is 12 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the loop into

```
while (fscanf(file, "%s", buffer) == 1) {
    length = strlen(buffer);
    // ...
}
```

Because `feof(file)` still returns `0` after the last successful `fscanf()`. It returns non-0 after the first *failed* `fscanf()`.

Regarding `insert_sorted()`, look at the following lines:

```
            head->next = &dat;
            return;
```

Since `dat` is a local *object*, saving its address leads to invalid address once the function returns.

Comment: My problem isn't reading to the end, after 'ee' is read and fscanf fires again for 'fff', I start seeing memory corruption.

Comment: @VaughanHilts Then please show your `insert_sorted()`. At the same time, you could run `valgrind` to check for memory corruption.

Comment: I edited in an example of the kind of corruption going on. I'll also include my sorted method.

Comment: @VaughanHilts Edited for issues in `insert_sorted()`.

Comment: That's interesting, why would that cause issues when a fscanf is fired, though? I'll try fixing that immediately, at any rate.

Comment: Sure enough, that fixed it... I created the object on the heap rather than the stack and its good to go now. Although, I feel like there should be a better way to do that... there's always round 2 I guess. :) Is there a way I can prevent these kind of errors?

Comment: Run `valgrind` and fix all issues reported.

Answer (score 1):

You're not testing for end of file correctly. In general, it's not correct to use feof, but instead to test the return value of the function with which you read from the file.

fscanf returns the number of entities that it was able to read. So in your case you would test that it returned 1, which would indicate a successful read. And to avoid buffer overflow, you can put a limit on the number of characters to read with a number between the % and the s.

And there's no reason to be so stingy with your buffer size.

So:

```
void insert_words(FILE* file, node_type* list)
{
    char buffer[128];

    while (fscanf(file, "%127s", buffer) == 1) {
        insert_sorted(list, buffer);
    }
}
```

BTW, you're not reading "line by line" but "space-delimited string by space-delimited string". To read the file line-by-line you could use fgets.

And before you say "that's not the problem", try it first. These are the only problems that could come from this function.

Comment: The correction is definitely appreciated, although this is not my bug.  My bug appears before I even reach the end -- when my application reads in the token 'fff', part of list gets overwritten. I'll edit in some more information..